# Hyperbolic paraboloid : a special example with perpendicular lines

Tags: geometry, 3d

Let $a>0$. Take the hyperbolic paraboloid, denoted $S$, defined as the set of $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{a^2}=z.
$$
We know that an hyperbolic paraboloid is doubly ruled surface. But in this particular case, one can show that for every point $M$ of the hyperbolic paraboloid, the two lines $D_1$ and $D_2$ that are contained in $S$ and such that $M\in D_1$ and $M\in D_2$ are perpendicular.

Take $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in S$.
I found that the line $D_1$
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
x/a - y/a - x_0/a+y_0/a &=&  0\\ 
(x/a + y/a)(x_0/a-y_0/a)-z&=&0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
is contained in $S$ and $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in D_1$. I also found that the vector
$$
\vec{v}_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1/a \\
-1/a \\
0
\end{pmatrix} \wedge \begin{pmatrix}
1/a(x_0/a-y_0/a) \\
1/a(x_0/a-y_0/a) \\
-1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1/a \\
1/a \\
2/a^2(x_0/a-y_0/a)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is a direction vector for $D_1$.

Similarly, the line $D_2$
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
x/a + y/a - x_0/a-y_0/a &=&  0\\ 
(x/a - y/a)(x_0/a+y_0/a)-z&=&0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
is contained in $S$ and $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in D_2$. I also found that the vector
$$
\vec{v}_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1/a \\
1/a \\
0
\end{pmatrix} \wedge \begin{pmatrix}
1/a(x_0/a+y_0/a) \\
-1/a(x_0/a+y_0/a) \\
-1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1/a \\
1/a \\
-2/a^2(x_0/a+y_0/a)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is a direction vector for $D_2$. So I should get that
$$
\vec{v_1}\cdot \vec{v_2} =0
$$
but with my calculations, I get that
$$
\vec{v_1}\cdot \vec{v_2} = - 4/a^4(x_0^2-y_0^2) = -2/a^2z_0.
$$
So obviously, I'm doing something wrong...Could you help me for this problem?

Comment: I haven't checked your calculations, but in the $a = 1$ case, $z = x^{2} - y^{2}$ is congruent to $z = 2xy$. It's easy to see geometrically that the rulings (here, $x = \text{constant}$ or $y = \text{constant}$) are not generally perpendicular, only when they intersect in the plane $z = 0$. This is consistent with your calculations. The problem, then, is the expectation that the rulings are everywhere perpendicular. What's true is, for each ruling of one family, _there exists_ a perpendicular ruling of the other family.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you! So it seems that I misunderstood the statement about the type of hyperbolic paraboloid...